# magento2 fedex shipping is not working

Tags: magento2, shipping, fedex

I have generated a test key on fedex developer account & configured all needed details in Magento 2, but all the time I am getting message:

> Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time

at frontend cart & checkout page. The credentials are correct than why it is not calculating shipping cost ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for this problem. I request you to check the following things,

1. Please ensure that you have selected the API mode as Test.
2. Ensure that your maximum package weight is greater than the product weight.

Note: If the above 2 is correct. Then check in your error_log and debug files to know what went wrong.

For detailed Troubleshooting, you can visit this [article](https://www.xadapter.com/trouble-shooting-magento-2-shipping-extensions/). I fixed my maximum package weight problem referring it.

Comment: What is the way to select API mode as Test ?

Comment: Navigate to your FedEx shipping method settings by Stores->Configuration->Sales->Shipping Methods. Now set the sandbox mode to yes. Yes is for test account and No is for live account.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the India to India domestic shipping to work you need to add in a PurposeOfShipment type to the request. This line is not standard in Magento's code for Fedex shipping. That line will be added into CustomsClearanceDetail header as a child under CommercialInvoice then a line under that is Purposewhich can have any value that PurposeOfShipment has.

Here is an example of the request I used that returned proper shipping estimates for India to India shipping.

```
'CustomsClearanceDetail' => array(
     'CommercialInvoice' => array(
       'Purpose' => "SOLD"
    )
),
```

Also, Rates are not available for test credentials,use production for testing rates!

Answer (score 0):

In order for the India to India domestic shipping to work you need to add in a PurposeOfShipment type to the request. This line is not standard in Magento's code for Fedex shipping. That line will be added into CustomsClearanceDetail header as a child under CommercialInvoice then a line under that is Purposewhich can have any value that PurposeOfShipment has.

**please tell me** where  to locate these files to be changed in magento 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. It turned out that I was missing the SOAP PHP extension. After adding that, it worked. I found a SoapClient error in

```
<magento directory>/var/report/api/<API report ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You must have to assign weight from admin side for specific product you check.**

Answer (score -1):

I have been able to use fedex in india, however there is a need to apend the Carrier.php file in mangento 2.0

1. magento Root directory/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model
2. apend Carrier.php file at line no 410.
   and do the following

a. search for ‘CustomsClearanceDetail’ => [

b. add the following in below the lines
‘CommercialInvoice’ => array (
‘Purpose’ => “SOLD”
),

this worked out for me at staging.readers.in

Comment: Dont edit core files, use a plugin or preference in di to do this instead.